# Nodejs Application Performance Testing best Tool

Tags: node.js, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a Node.js application for this would like to conduct Performance Testing. I have used JMeter tool to record business scenario but that requests are having some encrypted information but those values are inputs and would like to do parameterization with CSV file.

I feel like JMeter is not a best option for Node.js Application. Can someone please suggest open source tool for Node.js Application.

Answer (score 6):

Any load testing tool acts on [HTTP protocol level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview), they know nothing about underlying backend technology stack so it can be either NodeJS or PHP or Java or .NET or Python - from the load testing tool perspective it is just a web server which responds to HTTP Requests.

Therefore there is no "special" tool for NodeJS load testing, if you're a JavaScript developer you may find [Artillery.io](https://artillery.io/) or [k6.io](https://k6.io/) more useful as you will be able to define your tests in your "native" JavaScript language and possibly will be able to re-use some functions which perform encryption of parameters.

If you are not a developer by nature - JMeter should be a very good candidate tool as it normally doesn't require any programming language knowledge (however if you want there are [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) which support a variety of scripting languages including JavaScript, however it is recommended to use [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for performance reasons).

Moreover, there is [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) for JMeter which enables simulating [AJAX requests](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) and other free load testing tools lack this support.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try https://github.com/anywhichway/benchtest. Note, Benchtest should only be one part of your performance testing, you should also use simulators that emulate real world conditions and test your code at the application level to assess network impacts, module interactions, etc.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion is to use K6.io, it is more useful as you will be able to convert your script from postman collection to k6 script, then execute and monitor your test results easily.